# In tcl how do I get fractional part of given number

Tags: tcl

In tcl code, I want to get fractional part of given number.

I tried following code

```
set a 2.9999383 

expr {fmod($a,1)} gives me 0.9999383000000002
```

How do I get correct fractional part without additional decimal digits ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You've discovered the fun to be had with floating point numbers! The trick is to get a guess of how many digits there are after the floating point (doesn't have to be too accurate!) and use that with `format` to do the rounding off.

```
format "%.*g" [string length $a] [expr {fmod($a, 1.0)}]
```

That produces `0.9999383` with your test data, and yet makes few assumptions about the input…

Answer (score 0):

Floats are imprecise estimates. Those "extra digits" are simply a result of the system's best attempt to approximate a decimal in a base-two system.

You can round the float to get rid of the trailing 2:

```
format "%.2f" $a
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use string split otherwise I guess:

```
set a 2.9999383
set fraction "0.[lindex [split $a "."] 1]"
puts $fraction
0.9999383
```

That'll avoid having to see whether the fraction got deformed and/or needs to be rounded or not.